# rules_invoke_component() - Getting the value of the Provided Variable

Tags: rules, hooks

In my code, I am using rules_invoke_component() to invoke a Rules Component.

On that Rules Component, have 2 variables.

1. Parameter
2. Provided

[image]

I am successfully able to invoke the Rule and send the Parameter Variable to it (In this case it was $node). But I am just confused on how to get the value of the Provided Variable.

[image]

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the "[Tiny book of Rules](https://www.bryanbraun.com/tiny-book-of-rules/2.-Coding-for-Rules/5-invoking-components-programmatically.html)":

```
Invoking components programmatically 

Rules components are handy tools for allowing site builders to customize their own actions and 
conditions. If you are writing a module that allows site builders to set custom conditions (or 
actions), you can let them set these up as Rules components and then evaluate selected components 
programmatically. This works in a way analogous to invoking events, by using 
rules _invoke_component() . 

The first argument is the (machine) name of the component, and any subsequent arguments are 
variables sent to the component. 

// Included somewhere in your custom module. 

$component name = $settings [' rules component name']; 

// Any variables provided from the component are returned from its evaluation. 

$result = rules _invoke_component ( $component_name, $var 1, $var 2 ) ;
```

So the last 2 lines in the quote above should answer your question.